# Without changing condition in if statement i need to print else statement by giving any value to i?

Tags: c, if-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i =-1;
    if(1< i <10){
        printf("1");
    } else {
        printf("2");
    }
}
```

```
expected output: 2
present output: 1
```

Comment: `1< i <10` - is not how you check ranges in C. It is the same as `(1 < i) < 10`, which is always true regardless of `i` value..

Comment: Even we are getting the output as 1 @Eugene Sh

Comment: Even we? Everyone will get `1` with this code. Always.

Comment: What are the changes that you are allowed to make? Is this a puzzle? Or did you make it up by yourself?

Comment: yes but without changing the condition in if i need to print 2 for any value of i.

Comment: Then swap `1` and `2`....Or just put two `2`s...

Comment: Anyway. As stated it looks like absolutely pointless exercise.

Comment: Try `int i =-1;` --> `#define i 10,10` - yeah - it is a cheat.

Comment: Another cheat... you can `#define printf(x) printf("2")`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Nice - likely endless ways to "work" outside this [box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50630026/without-changing-condition-in-if-statement-i-need-to-print-else-statement-by-giv#comment88270042_50630026)

Answer (score 3):

In the Boolean expression `1 < i < 10` is evaluated left-to right and `1 < i` is either true (1) or false (0); so in the subsequent comparison, both `0 < 10` and `1 < 10` are always true, regardless of the value of `i`.

It is not therefore possible to obtain the output `2` without changing (possibly correcting?) the condition.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Clifford

Comment: note: < is a relational operation and the order of evaluation is left-to-right.

Comment: @Edenia - clarification added.

Answer (score 1):

Replace with the following:

```
if ((i > 1) && (i < 10)) {
```

Then you can trigger the else block by giving to `i` a value stricly comprised (please suggest a better word) between 1 and 10.

Due to operators precedence it is not possible to achieve this without changing the condition. (The whole condition reduces to true in every cases.)

Comment: Not an answer - the question states "without changing the condition".

Comment: Without changing the code the mission is impossible.

Comment: I knew this way but we should not change the condition in if.